# Best Practice for Handling an Incomplete Question

Tags: discussion

I recently wrote this question: [OperationContext Properties throw ObjectDisposedException After Writing Custom ServiceHostFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129084/operationcontext-properties-throw-objectdisposedexception-after-writing-custom-s?noredirect=1#comment48369701_30129084)

At the time I thought that the underlying cause of the problem was something to do with the communication stack, but as I learned more about the actual cause, I realized that it was a coding error that was not shown in the question.

What is the best way to close this question? Is it to answer it in two days? Is it to delete it, or flag it?  Put the real cause in the question?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# so I'm not going to bother going through the body but could whatever the issue is be of help to someone else if you add the missing part? And, if so, is the missing code and posted code relevant to each other? If yes and yes then I would answer. If either is no then I would probably delete though know that deleted posts can contribute to a timeout. So that is up to you. If you don't have previous "bad" behavior then deleting one post shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the question so that it *is* a complete question.  If you have a solution, you can also post an answer with your solution.

Don't put the answer in the question itself; questions are for asking questions, *answers* are for answering those questions.

If you can't make the question complete then vote/flag to close it as Unclear, or possibly one of the more specific close reasons (i.e. doesn't contain a reproducible example) if they apply.

If you don't see any hope of turning the question into an answerable question, and there isn't any useful content posted by another user already, deleting it would be appropriate.

Comment: @codeMagic thanks, didn't realize it was his question.

Comment: While I'm turning it into a better question, is there a way I should flag it?

Comment: @stephen If you're in the process of editing it, no, there really isn't anything to flag it for.

Comment: What do you do when the question is incomplete because it is missing critical details (eg, missing th eMain() function, but has the class which causes the error)

Comment: @jrharshath You'd do exactly what the question described; vote to close (there's a close reason specifically for not providing an MCVE).  Downvoting would also typically be appropriate.  You can also vote to delete if/when it becomes clear that the OP isn't going to add the needed information.

Comment: @Servy Sure I'd vote to close, but it feels wrong to bucket the question as "unclear". The question sure is clear, its just incomplete. I suppose I'm getting too pedantic... :)